# Flutter Keyboard Adds Padding Twice Its Height

Tags: android, flutter

Recently came across an issue where as the keyboard shows when focusing on a TextField, the app pads the bottom twice the height of the keyboard. This displaces the TabBar and extends ListViews. It affects all displays as soon as I focus on a TextField.

[No Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JiDt.png)

[Keyboard Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYPZn.png)

Issue seem to have arised when I updated Gradle to 4.1 in attempt to use the google_sign_in plugin.

Below is my main_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Utils/lang.dart';
import 'themes.dart';
import 'page_dashboard.dart';
import 'page_explore.dart';
import 'page_inbox.dart';
import 'page_new_quest.dart';
import '../fields.dart';
import 'page_chat_conversation.dart';
import 'page_log_in.dart';
import '../fab_dialer/flutter_fab_dialer.dart';
import 'welfare_overlay.dart';
import 'page_log_in_test.dart';
import 'page_splash.dart';

enum Pages {Newsfeed, Dashboard, Explore, Inbox}
enum Menu {AboutUs, LogOff}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Pay It Forward',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Pay It Forward'),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/newQuest': (BuildContext context) => new PageNewQuest(),
        '/conversation': (BuildContext context) => new PageChatConversation(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Pages _currentPage = Pages.Dashboard;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationBar = new BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.all_inclusive), title: new Text(PIFLocale.NEWSFEED), backgroundColor: Colors.cyan),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text(PIFLocale.DASHBOARD), backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.explore), title: new Text(PIFLocale.EXPLORE), backgroundColor: Colors.amber),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: new Icon(Icons.email), title: new Text(PIFLocale.INBOX), backgroundColor: Colors.orange),
        ],
        onTap: (i) => setState( () => _currentPage = Pages.values[i]),
        currentIndex: _currentPage.index
    );

    List<FabMiniMenuItem> floatingActionButtonList = new List();
    floatingActionButtonList.add(new FabMiniMenuItem(
      onPressed: (){Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/newQuest');},
      textColor: Colors.white,
      chipColor: Colors.redAccent,
      fabColor: Colors.white,
      icon: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.redAccent),
      elevation: 4.0,
      text: "New Request",
      tooltip: "Hello",
      heroTag: "Abc"
    ));
    floatingActionButtonList.add(new FabMiniMenuItem(
      onPressed: (){},
      textColor: Colors.white,
      chipColor: Colors.redAccent,
      fabColor: Colors.white,
      icon: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.redAccent),
      elevation: 4.0,
      text: "New Offer",
      heroTag: "def"
    ));

    Scaffold mainScaffold = new Scaffold(
      body: _getNewSubPage(),
      //drawer: new Drawer(child: new DrawerContent()),
      floatingActionButton: new FabDialer(
        floatingActionButtonList,
        Colors.redAccent,
        new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,
    );

    return new WillPopScope(
        child: mainScaffold,
        onWillPop: () {
          if (_currentPage != Pages.Dashboard){
            setState(() => _currentPage = Pages.Dashboard);
          } else{
            return showDialog(
              context: context,
              child: new AlertDialog(
                title: new Text('Byeeee?'),
                content: new Text('Are you sure you want to quit? \n真的要離開嗎？'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                    child: new Text('No'),
                  ),
                  new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                    child: new Text('Yes'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ) ?? false;
          }
        }
    );
  }


  Widget _getNewSubPage(){
    Widget child; // WELFARE
    switch (_currentPage)
    {
      case Pages.Newsfeed:
        child = new PageSplash();
        break;
      case Pages.Dashboard:
        child = new PageDashboard();
        break;
      case Pages.Explore:
        child = new PageExplore();
        break;
      case Pages.Inbox:
        child = new PageInbox();
        break;
      default:
        child = new PageDashboard();
    }
    /*
    if (_currentPage != Pages.Dashboard){
      return new Stack(
          children:[
            child,
            new WelfareOverlay(),
          ]
      );
    } else {
      return child;
    }*/
    return child;
  }
}

/*Widget PopUpMenu<Menu>() {
  return new PopUpMenuButton<Menu>(

  )
}*/
```

This is the test page I've used to demonstrate

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'themes.dart';

class PageSplash extends StatefulWidget{


  @override
  State createState() {
    return new PageSplashState();
  }
}

class PageSplashState extends State<PageSplash> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new TextField(),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.